# Azure redirects to azure test site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

my website which is hosted on Azure, redirects to the Azure test site link when I click a link.

For example, my website is http://www.williampross.com. When I click on a link it goes to the Azure test site like: http://wpr.azurewebsites.net/programming-books/

I want it to go to main URL rather than the azurewebsites URL instead (which is also a valid link).

Comment: I looked the source code and all the links has `wpr.azurewebsites.net` address and that's why users are redirected to that site. Can you share how you're creating these links?

Comment: In Azure under "Configure" -> "domain names" there are three things listed: www.williampross.com, williampross.com, wpr.azurewebsites.net

I also went to Namecheap where I bought there URL and there are 5 entries under advanced DNS:

     Type                        Host                                Value     
1.  A record                    @                                 IP address (filled in)
2.  CNAME record          @                                 wpr.azurewebsites.net
3.  CNAME record          awverify          awverify.wpr.azurewebsites.net

Comment: 4. CNAME Record         awverify.www        awverify.wpr.azurewebsites.net
5. CNAME Record         www                      wpr.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine with the a record & cname records & therefore suggest that the Azure part of the setup is fine.

I believe that your issue is related to the Wordpress setup.  Log into your Dashboard, Go Settings>General & change the **Wordpress Address (URL)** & **Site Address (URL)** to http://www.williampross.com (goes without saying...make sure you back up your database before you start tweaking).

Comment: Another quick point - once the above works, go back into the Azure Portal & add williampross.com to the domain list (you have already done **www.**williampross.com) & add the cname records to the dns server.  Otherwise, the site will load at www.williampross.com but not at williampross.com. Theres no need to alter anything in Wordpress further than as per the original answer.

Comment: The wordpress solution worked! You were right that I needed to change those Wordpress Address and Site Address fields. So not really an Azure issue after all. Thanks.

Comment: No probs. Can you mark the answer as correct (press the tick)?

Comment: Yea sure, clicked the click, still new to the site.